# Bit twiddling: From ulong, get bitmask representing which bytes were non-zero

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Say we have an 8-byte ulong. For each byte, we want to know whether it is zero or non-zero. The desired result is a byte, whose 8 bits represent the "non-zeroness" of the original 8 bytes.

Is there a name for this operation or set of operations?

How can we achieve this very efficiently? An ideal solution would be branchless.

As an alternate requirement, a useful answer would be the position of the first non-zero byte. E.g. if the first non-zero byte is the third one, the answer would be 2 (0-based index). I realize this can be approached by counting the leading zeros of the initial requirement's answer, but perhaps this will allow a shortcut.

Comment: I just realized that for the alternate requirement, we could count the leading zeros, giving us the position of the first 1-bit, and divide by 8 to get that position in whole bytes.

Comment: Check [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) and all the other stuff on that page for inspiration. This exact operation isn't there, but some variation of one of the tricks there will probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

This might help -

```
    private void Evaluate(ulong n)
    {
        ulong f = 255;
        int r = 0, p = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            r >>= 1;
            var t = n & f;
            if (t > 0)
            {
                r += 128;
                if (p < 0)
                    p = i;
            }
            f <<= 8;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Resulting byte: {r}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Position: {p}");
    }
```

What I have done is bitwise ANDed every byte of input 8 byte number with 255(1111 1111). If the result is one I right shifted one bit for result and added 128(1000 000).

For position I initialized `p = -1` in case number is zero. Otherwise, assign first index of `> 0'.

There are lot of optimization possible like comparing input number to zero and if true simply return 0 for result and -1 for position.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the long by 8 bits and look at each byte independently (i.e. check if the byte == 0). Using the index of the byte, you can set the value in the resulting byte by shifting a 1 into that bit index.

```
    private byte TestULong(ulong value)
    {
        byte result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var test = (byte)(value >> (i * 8));
            if (test != 0)
            {
                result = (byte)(result | (1 << i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that there is a purely math-based approach to this, but I can't seem to suss it out. Otherwise, the most efficient way to do this would be with a loop and some bit-wise comparisons:

```
public static byte Evaluate(ulong n) {
    ulong mask = 0xFF;
    byte result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if ((n & (mask << (i * 8))) != 0) {
            result |= (byte)(1 << i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The mask is a preconfigured value where every bit in a single byte is 1 (255 in decimal, FF in hexadecimal). You offset the mask by `i * 8` to get it to cover the nth byte of the input and then use a bitwise-AND to get the value of that byte. All you need to do is check if that byte value is non-zero, and if it is, set the corresponding bit of the result byte to 1. (This can be done with either an addition or a bitwise-OR, so I opted to go the OR route to keep with the bitwise theme.)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EA7NRw